How to request VFS to kindly accept all the documents
I plan to apply for a visa through VFS Delhi. A colleague shared his experience, mentioning that the VFS official refused to accept additional supporting documents for his application, which he believes led to his rejection. He said they didn't even take his ID card.
Is this a common occurrence? Are we not allowed to submit any documents other than those listed in their checklist, even if they could strengthen our application?
If you've faced a similar situation, could you please share how you handled it?
Thank you!

Why do you believe additional documents such as an ID card would strengthen the application?

Useful documents should be in the check-list. Else it would just slow down the process. There are exceptions, but it would apply for very few people (else they would add in the check-list), and so you should probably know it. For bureaucracy: you are not special, so follow instructions, do not add too much documents.

What purpose would an ID card serve, when the visa process already requires a passport? Considering your colleague doesn't understand the process, the most likely explanation for the rejection would be that misunderstanding. VFS can prevent one sort of error (submitting the wrong documents) but they can't fix the other sort (missing the right documents, in general those proving a strong reason to return to India)
